# get a result from flask

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a deep learning model (lstm) with keras, save it with `h5` and now I want to "hit" a web service in order to get back a category. This is the first time I have tried to do that so I am a little confused. I can not figure out how to take categories back. Also when I send a request to `http://localhost:8000/predict` I get the following error,

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your 
request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the 
application.
```

and in the notebook

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_3/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32) 
is not an element of this graph.
```

I try the solution from [enter link description here](https://kobkrit.com/tensor-something-is-not-an-element-of-this-graph-error-in-keras-on-flask-web-server-4173a8fe15e1) but is not working

The code so far is below

```
from flask import Flask,request, jsonify#--jsonify will return the data
import os
from keras.models import load_model

app = Flask(__name__)

model=load_model('lstm-final-five-Copy1.h5')

@app.route('/predict', methods= ["GET","POST"])
def predict():
    df_final = pd.read_csv('flask.csv')

    activities = df_final['activity'].value_counts().index

    label = LabelEncoder()
    df_final['label'] = label.fit_transform(df_final['activity'])

    X = df_final[['accx', 'accy', 'accz', 'gyrx', 'gyry', 'gyrz']] 
    y = df_final['label'] 

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    df_final = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ['accx', 'accy', 'accz', 'gyrx', 
    'gyry', 'gyrz'])
    df_final['label'] = y.values

    Fs = 50
    frame_size = Fs*2 # 200 samples
    hop_size = frame_size # 40 samples
    def get_frames(df_final, frame_size, hop_size):

       N_FEATURES = 6 #x,y,z (acc,gut)

      frames = []
      labels = []
      for i in range(0, len(df_final) - frame_size, hop_size):
          accx = df_final['accx'].values[i: i + frame_size]
          accy = df_final['accy'].values[i: i + frame_size]
          accz = df_final['accz'].values[i: i + frame_size]
          gyrx = df_final['gyrx'].values[i: i + frame_size]
          gyry = df_final['gyry'].values[i: i + frame_size]
          gyrz = df_final['gyrz'].values[i: i + frame_size]

          # Retrieve the most often used label in this segment
          label = stats.mode(df_final['label'][i: i + frame_size])[0][0]
          frames.append([accx, accy, accz, gyrx, gyry, gyrz])
          labels.append(label)

      # Bring the segments into a better shape
      frames = np.asarray(frames).reshape(-1, frame_size, N_FEATURES)
      labels = np.asarray(labels)

      return frames, labels

    X, y = get_frames(df_final, frame_size, hop_size)

    pred = model.predict_classes(X)
    return jsonify({"Prediction": pred}), 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=False)
```

Comment: Try adding "GET" in the list of methods

Comment: thank you. when i add "GET" this error occur Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: Can you post the error log in your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems in your '/predict' **POST** endpoint you arent returning any values which is why you arent getting back a category as you expect.

If you wanted to add a **GET** method you could add something like what is mentioned below,

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def check_server_status():
   return ("Server Running!")
```

And in the **POST** method your case you could return your prediction in the endpoint,

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    # Add in other steps here

    pred = model.predict_classes(X)
    return jsonify({"Prediction": pred}), 201
```

Comment: thank you for the answer is it necessary to have a get function?

Comment: Nope. I just mentioned it in case you wanted to use a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: thanks for you effort but still this not work,I get back Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: You could move all the preprocessing and data read steps outside your the predict() endpoint function (also save final dataframes to a csv and load that directly) and maybe only have the prediction related processing in the endpoint which might help in debugging.

Comment: i move all the preprocessing steps in an above shell.  the predict now is as you specify above but again when I go to http://localhost:8000/ I get back The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: so step 1: load the libraries, step 2:load the model, step 3:load the dataset, step 4: do the preprocess,  step 5:@app.route('/') def getmodel():return str (model), step 6:@app.route('/predict', methods= ["GET","POST"]) def predict():pred model.predict_classes(X) return jsonify({"Prediction": pred}), 201 step 6:if __name__ == '__main__': app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=False) and I get this error ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_3/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 6), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you need to install pandas if you haven't by doing `pip install pandas` and import it as `import pandas as pd`
Also you can add "GET" method in your `/prediction` endpoint like:

```
@app.route("/predict", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But again I get back  Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL. And how can I return the prediction as response?

Comment: Oh yes. I have made an edit to the code by adding "GET". You can refer to the answer given by @satilog below for returning predictions as response.

Comment: it does not work, i follow your suggestion and the prediction function from satilog but i get back Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: @ AKA can i ask something. i think that I mislead the whole procedure. The data that I load here is the same with the model that i load here. Is this ok? or maybay i must load data that the model has not seen before? also I think that this route is not necessary @app.route('/')
def getmodel():
    return str (model)

Comment: Right. I think getmodel function is not necessary. Try removing/comment it and make request like "http://localhost:8000/predict"

Comment: i get this back Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: also the localhost :8000 returns back The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: @ AKA hi,  i update the code above. Do you have any other ideas?